# Logback's Syslog Appender

Tags: slf4j, logback, syslog, appender

I've read logback's documentation multiple times on the syslog appender. I am under the impression that a syslog daemon runs on every computer, so I set up the configuration just as they have it in their example. When I run the program no errors occur yet when the system log is checked, nothing has been logged there.

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
  <syslogHost>my ip adress</syslogHost>
  <facility>USER</facility>
  <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
</appender>`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked that syslog is configured to receive connections via UDP? On my installation it was disabled by default, and had to be uncommented in the .conf file.